# Xbee Explorer dongle through USB

Tags: usb, wireless, xbee

How do I install an Xbee Explorer dongle with Xbee through the USB port on a rasp?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it uses a standard FTDI USB to Serial chip, so it should appear as a serial device on `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

Comment: I don't have the equipment here right now! But I recall that I found it at /dev/usb/001/008.

Comment: I also tried ftdi_eeprom --read-eeprom /dev/bus/001/008 ftdi-backup.conf without success.... Sorry I should be bus... not usb!

Comment: I can now see it at /dev/ttyUSB0. How do I config it?

Comment: I'm winging it here, as I don't have XBees, but advanced configuration can only be done under Windows with the [X-CTU](http://www.digi.com/support/productdetail?pid=3352&amp;osvid=57&amp;type=utilities "X-CTU") tool. Simple configuration can be done from a terminal using Hayes commands.